# Recursive function is crashing when run

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am writing a program which involves linked lists. I have written a function which returns the n-th node in the linked list, which calls itself recursively. My program compiles and runs up until the recursive function and then crashes. Here is the constructor for the nodes as well as the recursive function:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList():
    head(head){
        sizeInt = 0;
}

Node* LinkedList::get_nth(const int& n) const {
    Node* node = new Node();
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++){
        node = get_nth(counter + 1);
    }
    return node;
 }
```

What is the problem with this function? Let me know if you need anymore details or code.

Comment: So far it's only been a maximum of 10

Comment: Crashes how? What's the error message?

Comment: how do you ever expect this recursion to end ? (apart from when the `int` overflows or the stack runs out of space)

Comment: My compiler gives no errors. Just "program.exe has stopped working". I am quite new to programming and am not too familiar with how to use a debugger effectively, but as far as I can see, my debugger isn't picking anything up. I have pinpointed that this is the problem by preforming my own debugging using a `cout` before and after the function is called.

Comment: A line by line debugger would *certainly* pick something up.

Comment: The answers you've got so far about the infinite recursion are right; anyway, even if you fix that, I think your design is wrong. A get function shouldn't create a new object. It should explore the list, find it, and return it, without creating anything new. Otherwise, who exactly will take care of deleting the object? This is difficult to manage and error prone. Don't use `new` at all in this function and I think you'll get a better result.

Comment: "My compiler gives no errors." Sure, because from a syntactical point of view there are none. At most, if it was smart enough to understand what is going on, it could give you a warning, but it can't give you an error, because the one you have is a logical one. Compilers deal with syntax, not with logic. The program can be compiled and run. It's just that it crashes. To find and fix that you need a debugger. This class of problems is out of any compiler's reach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursion is infinite. At every call to `get_nth` you start a loop which initially calls `get_nth(1)` and that will call `get_nth(1)` and that will call `get_nth(1)`... until the stack space runs out.

Hint for the solution: A recursive linear search needs no loop.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. So would something along the lines of this work:

Set counter = 1 outside of get_nth function. An `if` statement inside the function that returns node if `counter == n`. An `else` statement that calls `get_nth(counter + 1)`?

Comment: @KOB You can't start the recursive calls from the head of the list, so you should pass the node to the recursive search. Initial call would be to the head and the next one to head->next. With the node, pass the counter and decrement it on recursion. When you call it with 0, return the node.

Comment: @KOB If n is greater than 0, finding the n:th node from the current one is the same as finding the (n-1):th from the next one. Don't use globals. Don't use loops.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing to block the recursion (among others, there is a recursive call with `n` increased to `n + 1`.)

This is overflowing your stack, and the program will crash as a result of that.